# how can I pass a a parameter to an event handler within map() function?

Tags: reactjs

The following routine calls an event handler when a checkbox is selected or deselected:

```
        {deliveries.map((x) => (
          <tr>
            <td className="dataTableCell">
              <input type="checkbox" 
              onChange={(x) => {
                this.setSelectedDelivery({x.DeliveryId})
              }} />
            </td>
          <tr>
        ))}
```

I tried passing the x.DeliveryId parameter as x.DeliveryId and {x.DeliveryId} but neither of these approaches worked.  How do I need to sructure this code in order to successfully pass the x.DeliveryId value as a parameter to the event handler?

Comment: it should be `onChange={() => this.setSelectedDelivery({x.DeliveryId})}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing that when you are doing the:

```
onChange={(x) => { this.setSelectedDelivery({x.DeliveryId}) }}
```

The `x` value is been overwritten by the event of the onChange method, thats why the `x.DeliveryId` is failing, because the `event` (in this case `x`) doesn't have the `DeliveryId`property.

One way to solve it is to add two parameters to you `onChange` method one for the event and other for the variable that you are passing this is in case that you are using any property of the `event` :

```
onChange={(event, x) => { this.setSelectedDelivery(x.DeliveryId) }}
```

I you are not using any property on the `event`just don't pass any parameter to your `onChange` method:

```
onChange={() => { this.setSelectedDelivery(x.DeliveryId) }}
```

**Edit:**
Im not sure how `setSelectedDelivery` is build, but i can see that you are passing an `object` without `values`, but i assume that you only need the `id` that's why you are seeing the Error that you mentioned con the comments, so you will have to pass just the `x.DeliveryId` to your `setSelectedDelivery`

Comment: I tried that but VS Code returns the following syntax error with that setup:
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: Which sample are you using and why did you choose that?

Comment: @user12617173 i edited the answer please check it out

Comment: here's an interesting bit of info.  if I use that approach in the answer and alert the value in the event handler function, then the alert displays "undefined."  however, if I just pass "x" to the event handler (as opposed to x.DeliveryId) and then alert x.DeliveryId *from the event handler function* then the expected delivery id is displayed in the alert.  any idea what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: nvm my last comment - this is working as expected now thanks